# Cannot read property 'name' of null. Could do with someone taking a look

Tags: javascript, jsx

I'm in a bit of a bind here.  The code should be right, but Chrome keeps saying there's a uncaught type reference on line 27.

It can't read the property 'name' of null.  I've gone over this code about three times already and can't find why its giving me issues.

Was hoping another set of eyes could take a look.

```js
var React = require("react");
var actions = require("../actions/SchoolActions");

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            name: "",
            tagline: "",
        };
    },
    addSchool: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        actions.addSchool(this.state);
    },
    handleInputChange: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = e.target.name;
        var state = this.state;
        state[name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(state);
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <form className="form" onSubmit={this.addSchool}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="control-label" htmlFor="name">
                        School Name:
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="name"
                        name="name"
                        value={this.state.name}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        placeholder="School Name"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label className="control-label" htmlFor="tagline">
                        Tagline:
                    </label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        id="tagline"
                        name="tagline"
                        value={this.state.address}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                        placeholder="Tagline"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <button className="btn" type="submit">
                        Add School
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: You should start by wrapping all of your properties in quote marks.  Example:
    <div name="foo"></div>
is much better than
    <div name=foo></foo>
Especially since some of those items are data, and may contain unexpected quotes, spaces, etc...

Your code example isn't really complete.  Could you create a plunkr or similar?

Comment: Well there's a ton of different files and folders so I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Activate Developer Tools in Chrome, add a break-point at beginning of `handleInputChange` then do some actual input change and the code will pause at that moment. Take a look at values of different variables and step over each line to find the exact issue.